# How to add a button in Android application title

Tags: android

I just want to add a button (may be a refresh button) in the title of an application in my android application.

Please guide... and provide code block if possible...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about a [Actionbar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) but that does not offer backwards compatibility prior to API Level 11.  There are several open source actionbar implementations, such as [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar), [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock), or [this](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid).  Or, you can simply create one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check this API tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.html

or this Stackoverflow article:

[Android: How to create a Dialog with a Scrolling title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578929/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-with-a-scrolling-title)