# Wrap android dialog title on multiple lines

Tags: java, android, dialog, google-api

Is there a way to wrap a title in a Android custom dialog box to multiple line ? Without having to make an AlertDialog ?

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle(itemTitle);
```

"itemTitle" is sometimes way too long and only half of the text is displayed.[image]

Comment: As I said previously "Is there a way to wrap a title in a Android custom dialog box to multiple line ? Without having to make an AlertDialog ?"

So no, I am not using an AlertDialog. I'm using a custom dialog.

Comment: Did you extend the Dialog class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use popupwindow
http://virenandroid.blogspot.com/2011/11/custom-popupwindow-android.html

Comment: This does not answer the question, and the link is broken.

Answer (score 7):

Answer copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578929/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-with-a-scrolling-title)

You can make dialog title multiline:

```
TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
title.setSingleLine(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `TextView` at the beginning of whatever parent layout you are using for your dialog:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mydialogtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

and add:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mydialogtitle);
dialogTitle.setText("My dialog title");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inflate the title with a completely customized view, I think this is the easiest way. Something like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(infService);

View titleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_title, null);

builder.setCustomTitle(titleView);
```

Where R.layout.dialog_title can be a TextView with multiple lines, or anything you want.